# Как обьяснить странное поведение object.Equals при сравнении со строкой?

Tags: c#, .net, строки, сравнение, приведение-типов

```
string s1 = "test";
string RuntimeS1 = "test1".Substring(0, 4); // интернирования нет
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s1, RuntimeS1)); //  false, expected

object ObjectCastedRuntimeS1 = RuntimeS1;
Console.WriteLine(ObjectCastedRuntimeS1.Equals(s1)); // true, wat ?!
```

Comment: `Equals` переопределен в строке, полиморфизм же, апкаст на переопределенные методы не влияет.

Comment: Действительно,  aepot, у вас глаз алмаз. Если перенесете это в ответ, он будет лучшим.

Comment: Ответ ниже тоже правильный, здесь просто все сильно зависело от того, какое объяснение вам больше по душе, так что можете его принять. Кому надо - увидит мой комментарий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего странного, в первом случае ты сравниваешь референсы (ссылки на область оперативной памяти). Текст один, а в памяти лежат в разных местах

Во втором случае значения строк(видимо оно автоматом к строкам приводится). А строки одинаковые, потому и тру.

Comment: Ну то что референсы - понятно, но почему во втором случае значения строк. Как Equals у инстанса object работает? В моем понимании он сравнивает ссылочное равенство.

Comment: ну ты же сравниваешь  обджект со строкой. Вероятно же что он и пытается сравнивать значение строки, а если не удается, то сравнивает по ссылках.

Comment: если ты и вторую строку (s1) переведешь в обджект - вероятнее всего будет пытаться ссылками сравнивать. Попробуй

Comment: Можешь общее правило рассказать как работает Equals в таком случае? Так что бы туда вписывались и  строки и value types и reference types.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(ObjectCastedRuntimeS1.Equals((object)s1)); //   true

Comment: У меня не получилось понять к сожалению нифига. Тот пример главный в вопросе для  кастомного класса и структуры иначе отрабатывает. Возможно под капотом используються перегрузки строковых Equals или ==... не понятно...

Comment: окей, тогда оно кастует в стринг автоматом и сравнивает по `==`. А у стринга `==` перегружен для сравнения контента, а не по сравнению референсов. Хочешь сравнивать по референсу принудительно - используй `object.ReferenceEquals(s1, "text");`В общем и целом я вообще не понимаю принципиальности даного вопроса потому что какая разница) Раз ты уже знаешь что при таком использовании оно сравнивает значения - то и запомнил это и все. Если этот вариант не устраивает - можешь покурить исходники и разобраться:  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,65

Comment: Тот хелпер который работает в equals. Уходит куда-то во внешний код (extern - не покуришь).

Comment: "тогда оно кастует в стринг" - каким механизмом? Почему другие типы не кастует?

Comment: "какая разница" - если помнить не исключения, а общие правила/механизмы, то таким образом можно легко запомнить больший обьем информации.

Comment: ну тогда помни общий принцип что кастовать любой конкретный тип в object - это плохо и так делать нежелательно. И чем меньше ты будешь иметь дело с object - тем лучше. Такой принцип в ровно той же мере решает эту проблему только вовсе без запоминания чего-либо. А то ты пытаешься вставлять палки себе в колеса, а потом героически пытаешся бороться с проблемами которые сам же и создаешь. Я вот по пальцах могу пересчитать когда мне было необходимо иметь дело с обджектами за последние 3 года. Ноль раз)